# Do I have to recheck luggage in Heathrow Airport transferring from a flight on Delta to British Airways?

Tags: air-travel

My wife and I fly from Atlanta, Ga to London on 08/02/14, arriving at 12:15 on 08/03/14 on Delta Airlines. We will then fly directly to Dublin, Ireland on either the 14:05 or 17:25 flights on British Airways. Do we have to get our luggage in Heathrow and go through customs, then go to the British Airways ticket counter to check the luggage with them and then go back through security? I doubt Delta will check the bags through to a British Airways flight. We are currently booked on the 17:25 flight but would love to make the 14:05 flight but I have no idea how much time it would take to go through customs and then through the ticket line and then back through security. Can you help?

Comment: As you on a single ticket for both flights, or two separate tickets?

Comment: We have separate tickets for both flights.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately you will need to retrieve your bags and re-check them.  I haven't had this exact scenario, but I have flown on a mixed Delta/British Airways flight before, where customs didn't even play into it (Cape Town to Johannesburg on British, Johannesburg to Atlanta on Delta), and was forced to re-check my bags.

I don't know if any airlines have arrangements to transfer checked luggage like that, but British Airways and Delta (as of January 2014) certainly do not.

Comment: BA absolutely do had an interline agreement with DL, however that doesn't mean that they have to interline bags in every situations (eg, it often differs depending on whether you're on one ticket or two).  Even then, the question is regarding DL->BA, which is likely very different to BA->DL

Comment: Either way, they will be going thru Immigration at LHR due to the Common Travel Area agreement. I don't know if that would cause them to re-check in their luggage, but I would assume so.

Comment: CTA won't change things customs wise, you'll clear customs on arrival in Ireland, it'll all depend on the ticketing

Comment: The OP I believe is on two point-to-point ticket; _"we have separate tickets for the flights"_; so either way they have to be landed in the UK; which makes the whole luggage transfer issue moot.